# How to access db [Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'172.18.0.3' (using password: YES)] in docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file.

I would like to `build`them and connect to `DB`

```
version: '3'

services:
  api-server:
    build: ./api
    links:
      - 'db'
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - ./api:/src
      - ./src/node_modules
    tty: true
    container_name: api-server

  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./db/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    hostname: db
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db
    volumes:
      - './db:/config'
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    container_name: db
```

After `docker-compose build`

then `docker-compose up -d`

And then `docker exec -it api-server sh'

I could enter containers. and tried

`yarn ts-node node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:show`

typeorm command which connect to `DB`

But it returned

`Error during migration show: Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'172.18.0.3' (using password: YES)`

Are there any way to fix it?

Where is the wrong point of it ?

Thanks

Here is `docker logs db`

```
docker logs db
2020-09-15 11:57:44+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.31-1debian10 started.
2020-09-15 11:57:44+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-09-15 11:57:44+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.31-1debian10 started.
2020-09-15 11:57:44+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
2020-09-15T11:57:44.868762Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2020-09-15T11:57:46.939481Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
2020-09-15T11:57:47.252278Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2020-09-15T11:57:47.327831Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: abfbf3cb-f74a-11ea-bfe8-0242ac120002.
2020-09-15T11:57:47.331570Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2020-09-15T11:57:48.443477Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-09-15T11:57:48.733702Z 1 [Warning] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
2020-09-15 11:57:52+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized
2020-09-15 11:57:52+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
2020-09-15 11:57:52+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Waiting for server startup
2020-09-15T11:57:52.490209Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2020-09-15T11:57:52.492212Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.31) starting as process 77 ...
2020-09-15T11:57:52.497001Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2020-09-15T11:57:52.497114Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-09-15T11:57:52.497223Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-09-15T11:57:52.497332Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2020-09-15T11:57:52.497452Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-09-15T11:57:52.497542Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-09-15T11:57:52.498106Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-09-15T11:57:52.498434Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2020-09-15T11:57:52.501015Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2020-09-15T11:57:52.515593Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-09-15T11:57:52.518852Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2020-09-15T11:57:52.531163Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-09-15T11:57:52.555422Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-09-15T11:57:52.555698Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-09-15T11:57:52.665854Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-09-15T11:57:52.667159Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-09-15T11:57:52.667286Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-09-15T11:57:52.668320Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.31 started; log sequence number 2720554
2020-09-15T11:57:52.669761Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-09-15T11:57:52.669911Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2020-09-15T11:57:52.672485Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200915 11:57:52
2020-09-15T11:57:52.683725Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2020-09-15T11:57:52.683951Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2020-09-15T11:57:52.684864Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-09-15T11:57:52.684970Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2020-09-15T11:57:52.687815Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2020-09-15T11:57:52.704435Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2020-09-15T11:57:52.705512Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.31'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2020-09-15 11:57:53+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
2020-09-15 11:58:00+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating database mogucare_db
2020-09-15 11:58:00+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating user root
ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 1: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'%'
2020-09-15 11:58:02+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.31-1debian10 started.
2020-09-15 11:58:03+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-09-15 11:58:03+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.31-1debian10 started.
2020-09-15T11:58:03.406842Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2020-09-15T11:58:03.409690Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.31) starting as process 1 ...
2020-09-15T11:58:03.418038Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2020-09-15T11:58:03.418101Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-09-15T11:58:03.418117Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-09-15T11:58:03.418133Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2020-09-15T11:58:03.418152Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-09-15T11:58:03.418170Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-09-15T11:58:03.419647Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-09-15T11:58:03.420784Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2020-09-15T11:58:03.425652Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2020-09-15T11:58:03.448462Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-09-15T11:58:03.457474Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2020-09-15T11:58:03.473399Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-09-15T11:58:03.477057Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 2720554
2020-09-15T11:58:03.737975Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 7963136
2020-09-15T11:58:03.934900Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 12578409
2020-09-15T11:58:03.936536Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2020-09-15T11:58:03.936685Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2020-09-15T11:58:04.147681Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
2020-09-15T11:58:05.179148Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Apply batch completed
2020-09-15T11:58:05.286743Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-09-15T11:58:05.286809Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-09-15T11:58:05.286925Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-09-15T11:58:05.374586Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-09-15T11:58:05.376546Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-09-15T11:58:05.377004Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-09-15T11:58:05.378022Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-09-15T11:58:05.439607Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.31 started; log sequence number 12578409
2020-09-15T11:58:05.442005Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2020-09-15T11:58:05.454028Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-09-15T11:58:05.492756Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200915 11:58:05
2020-09-15T11:58:05.518753Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2020-09-15T11:58:05.518785Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2020-09-15T11:58:05.519497Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-09-15T11:58:05.519541Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2020-09-15T11:58:05.536601Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2020-09-15T11:58:05.537666Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2020-09-15T11:58:05.537947Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2020-09-15T11:58:05.538239Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-09-15T11:58:05.552491Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2020-09-15T11:58:05.574297Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2020-09-15T11:58:05.574997Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.31'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2020-09-15T11:59:47.472547Z 3 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'172.18.0.3' (using password: YES)
2020-09-15T12:03:15.760923Z 4 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'172.18.0.3' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: Hi have you tried connecting to the db from your host directly using MySQL Workbench or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is in MySQL database `mysql`, table `users`. The user you are connecting with doesn't have permission - either because it doesn't exist, you have the wrong password, or you have no rights to connect from your IP to the target database.

In many cases, MySQL docker containers come configured to only allow connections to localhost (127.0.0.1) which means you must either (a) use port forwarding or (b) grant the user permission to connect from anywhere (i.e. `%`). Sometimes there is also a configuration switch that will automatically do this for you - read the documentation for your db container.